# Ошибка ORA-39087: directory name is invalid при импорте резервной копии с impdp

Tags: oracle, импорт, oracle11g

Есть резервная копия БД. Сделана при помощи `expdp`, соответственно хочу восстановить ее при помощи `impdp`.

Делаю так, в командной строке:

```
C:\Users\waters>impdp ASPECTS/ASPECTS@SDMSVP DIRECTORY=C:\BackupDB DUMPFILE=ASPECTS.DMP
```

Результат такой:

```
Import: Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on Thu Jul 18 08:07:25 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Product
With the Partitioning, Oracle Label Security, OLAP, Data Mining,
Oracle Database Vault and Real Application Testing options
ORA-39002: invalid operation
ORA-39070: Unable to open the log file.
ORA-39087: directory name C:\BACKUPDB is invalid

C:\Users\waters>impdp ASPECTS/ASPECTS@SDMSVP DIRECTORY=C:\BackupDB DUMPFILE=ASPECTS.DMP
```

Где я не так сделал и почему такая ошибка?

База целая. Сейчас есть база которая работает и мне нужно сейчас накатить на работающую базу бекап чтобы актуализировать данные.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_export.htm#SUTIL840) сказано:

> `DIRECTORY=directory_object`
>   The directory_object is the name of a database directory object (**not the file path of an actual directory**).

Поэтому:

```
C:\Users\waters>impdp ASPECTS/ASPECTS@SDMSVP DIRECTORY=<directory_object> DUMPFILE=ASPECTS.DMP
```

Как точно называется `directory_object`, посмотрите так:

```sql
select directory_name 
from all_directories
where directory_path like '%BackupDB%'  
;
```

Если не нашли, то обратитесь к DBA.

Comment: я почему то думал что это path

Comment: Странно, а кто делал экспорт? Там тоже самое.

Comment: Экспорт делал не я, так сказать досталось по наследству, вот постигаю Оракл методом погружения